# Multilevel inheritance in java by using constructor

Tags: java, oop

Hello guys i am just beginner in java language.My program is Multilevel inheritance in java by using constructor.So in which i am facing some error while compiling my program.I will feel great if any one here solve my problem.

```
class bee
{   
    int x,y,z;

    bee(int x1,int y1,int z1)
    {
     x=x1;
     y=y1;
     z=z1;
     }
    void vol()
    {     
     int vol1=x*y*z;        
     System.out.println("Volume1="+vol1);
    }
}

class be extends bee
{   
    be(int x2,int y2,int z2)
    {
     x=x2;
     y=y2;
     z=z2;      
    }
}

class inh3
{
    public static void main(String args[])      
    {        
      be c=new be(10,20,30);
      c.vol();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the question here?

Comment: By copying your code to an IDE, I immediately saw what the problem is.  But the real problem in this question is that you should include the compiler error message here in your post.  Otherwise others will put this question on hold.

Comment: i am facing error "Cannot find symbol as constructor bee()

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're basically replicating the behavior of your superclass's constructor in the subclass's constructor.  You don't need to do this.  The superclass's constructor is already initializing those fields for you.  What you must do is *call* the superclass's constructor from the subclass's constructor.  This must be the first statement in the subclass's constructor.

```
class bee {
    int x, y, z;

    bee(int x1, int y1, int z1) {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
        z = z1;
    }

    // ...other methods...
}

class be extends bee {
    be(int x1, int y1, int z1) {
        super(x1, y1, z1);
    }
}
```

Now, when you create a `new be(10, 20, 30)`, the `be` constructor will pass the arguments along to the `bee` constructor, which will use them to initialize the `x`, `y`, and `z` fields.

To clarify: **every** constructor **must** call a constructor of the superclass.  If you do not do this explicitly, then the compiler will automatically insert a call to the "default" (parameterless) `super()` constructor if one exists.  If your superclass does not have a default constructor, and you do not call a super constructor explicitly, then it is an error, and your code will not compile.  That is presumably what is happening in your case.

Comment: Sometimes, a terrible question gets an undeservedly good answer.  Now is one of those times.

Comment: @Mike Strobel-Thanks a lot sir for replying.

Comment: class be extends bee, no?

Comment: Yea..must be typn mistake.